# getting the main image from another url?

Tags: php, html

I have a function which returns all img links of any web page but i want to take the image that represent the news  article  best . I know that it is a little hard question but every news articles have some main image on top of the article . I need to pick it among all of other images . Facebook and reddit like sites can do that . Do you have any kind of idea ? When members of my website shared a link , there should be a picture for it . I can take all url of images in a web page now i need to find main image .   :)

```html
function get_links($url) {

$xml = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$html = file_get_contents($url);

if(!$xml->loadHTML($html)) {
    $errors="";
    foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error)  {
        $errors.=$error->message."<br/>";
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
    print "libxml errors:<br>$errors";
    return;
}

// Empty array to hold all links to return 
$links = array();

//Loop through each <img> tag in the dom and add it to the link array 
foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName('img') as $link) {
    $url = $link->getAttribute('src');
    if (!empty($url)) {
        $links[] = $link->getAttribute('src');
    }
}

//Return the links 
return $links;
}
```

Comment: Look into [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/), if these meta tags exist it might be wise to consume them eg `<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.whatever.com/image.png" />` otherwise all you've got to go on is image size attributes or downloading the content yourself.

also, you get my vote for using DOMDocument!

Comment: If you're going against something like CNN.com that's got a consistent structure of articles, I'd start by using the console to check the image you're after and see if it's got some type of naming convention. For example, it looks like most CNN articles have a container on their main images with the following class `zn zn-large-media zn-body zn--idx-0 zn-has-one-container` However, I can't guarentee that's the same thing for all articles....

Comment: CNN is a great example of open graph usage eg [this article](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/07/11/politics/hillary-clinton-bernie-sanders/index.html) has the following tag `<meta content="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/160510183508-hillary-clinton-bernie-sanders-cnn-debate-large-tease.jpg" property="og:image">`

Comment: Thanks cnn.com was a example i know there is not any 100% solution of it . I just want my code should generate a suitable image for every link that shared by user

Comment: I might check image-sizes , bigger images tend to be better or article, header tags  might have best posibble images for the link . I really wonder how other big websites handle it .Like facebook or reddit .They often find best images for user posts .

Comment: Yes, if width and height attributes exist you could sort the image list by the images with the largest pixel size, but you also might need to account for image ratio to ensure you're getting good square/rectangular images. Dealing with dynamic sized images (eg css rules) may impose an issue. [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057082/how-do-you-find-the-main-picture-of-a-website-given-the-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your existing function, but if you want to preference the existence of the Open Graph data, add this before your `getElementsByTagName('img')` logic...

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $xml );
if( $xpathNodeList = $xpath->query('//meta[@property="og:image" and @content]') )
{
  return array( $xpathNodeList->item(0)->getAttribute('content') );
}
```

or add it to your array...

```
// Empty array to hold all links to return
$links = array();

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $xml );
if( $xpathNodeList = $xpath->query('//meta[@property="og:image" and @content]') )
{
  $links[] = $xpathNodeList->item(0)->getAttribute('content');
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i will try it . ^^